# How to disable JScrollBar when the JList inside JScrollPane does not fill entire area?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, jscrollbar

When the `jlist` only has a couple rows in it, I don't want the scroll bar to be able to scroll down because there is no need. Also, I am able to click on the empty rows, which highlights the row, even though it is empty. How can I disable the ability to highlight the row?

```
    public ProductApplication()
    {
    //WEST PANEL
    JPanel west = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    west.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(
            5, 5, 5, 5, Color.blue));
    west.add(new JTextField("Products"),
            BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pList = new JList(product);
    pList.setFixedCellHeight(20);
    pList.setFixedCellWidth(100);
    west.add(pList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    scrollpane = new JScrollPane(pList);
    west.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you needn't to show `JScrollBar` just create `JScrollPane` like next :

```
JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

2) You can manage highlight ability with help of [`ListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html).

Try next example:

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame(){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                init();
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                pack();
                setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void init() {
        DefaultListModel<String> model;
        JList<String> l = new JList<>(model = new DefaultListModel<>());
        l.setFixedCellHeight(20);
        l.setFixedCellWidth(100);
        model.addElement("");
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            model.addElement(i+"");
        }
        model.addElement("");
        model.addElement("5");
        l.setCellRenderer(getRenderer());
        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(l);
        jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        add(jScrollPane);

    }

    private ListCellRenderer<? super String> getRenderer() {
        return new DefaultListCellRenderer(){
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,boolean cellHasFocus) {
                Component listCellRendererComponent = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,cellHasFocus);
                if((value == null || value.toString().isEmpty()) && isSelected){
                    listCellRendererComponent.setBackground(list.getBackground());
                    ((JComponent)listCellRendererComponent).setBorder(null);
                }

                return listCellRendererComponent;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String... s){
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```